# How to declare dynamic properties with Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

```
/**
 * @param {Object} object
 * @param {(string|number)} name
 * @param {*} value
 */
var fabric = function(object, name, value) {
    object[name] = value;
};


fabric(Number, 'MAX_INTEGER', 9007199254740991);
// ...

console.log(Number.MAX_INTEGER); // 9007199254740991
```

**WARNING: JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property MAX_INTEGER never defined on Number 
    at line 14 character 12**

How to declare the dynamic properties without pre definitions?

**UPD:**

Number['MAX_INTEGER'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This falls under the [Restrictions for ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations) of the documentation. You must consistently refer to properties using either the dotted notation or quoted syntax. When you mix access, the compiler may rename the dotted access, but will not touch the quoted syntax and thus generate incorrect code.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to add properties in this way, you have two alternatives:

add a stub declaration in your externs (which will prevent renaming):

```
/** @const {number} */
Number.MAX_INTEGER;
```

or use @lends with a object literal:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} object
 * @param {Object} props
 */
var fabric2 = function(object, props) {
  for (var prop in props) {
    object[prop] = props[prop];
  }
};

fabric2(Number, /** @lends {Number} */ { MAX_INTEGER: 9007199254740991 });
```